# Apache: Site become unavailable when SSL is added

Tags: apache, ubuntu, tomcat, ssl, dns

I'm using Apache2 in ubuntu to rout the request to a tomcat webapp. I am also trying to add SSL into this. Below is the apache `000-default.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # Servers to proxy the connection, or;
    # List of application servers:
    # Usage:
    # ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # Example:
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/

    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.79/webapps/myglukose_messaging_portal/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine On
        # Set the path to SSL certificate
        # Usage: SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/STAR_myglukose_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private_key.key
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://<my-ip>/:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://<my-ip>/:8080/
        ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything was fine until I made the configuration for port 443. When that is made, the site simply becomes unavailable and the browser says "This site can’t be reached.  refused to connect.". My tomcat web app is deployed as "ROOT" so can be accessed with the port 80 configuration. Whats wrong here?

Comment: `apachectl configtest` will detect any error introduced during your changes. If there's no error during the check, check the error log

Comment: @Capsule: Where is this located?

Comment: @Capsule: Found it, error is `Certificate and private key localhost:443:0 from /etc/apache2/ssl/STAR_xxx_com.crt and /etc/apache2/ssl/private_key.key do not match`